# Link objective C library with C/ C++ Code base

Tags: iphone, ios, static

We have a library with objective-c classes and exposed C APIs to use these classes.
Now on iOS, i would like link it with c code base. 
How can i link this library statically with c code base.

Please suggest.

I tried the following and giving the following error :

```
$gcc -static cApp.c -L. -lTestLib 
ld: library not found for -lcrt0.o
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
$
```

Please help
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `-static` flag will prevent any dynamic linking, which in this case breaks the linking against the C runtime library. If TestLib is a static library then it should work if you just remove the `-static` flag.

```
$gcc cApp.c -L. -lTestLib
```

Note that this will try to build a binary for the host operating system. You may want to set the appropriate SDK and architecture if you build for iOS.